# C - multiple lvalue errors

Tags: c, while-loop, lvalue

I wanted to make a simple program that sums integers entered by user, only if the user enters them in a sequence (odd number, even number, odd number (..)) as long as the sum is lower than 100. This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_odd(int x)
{
    int i = x - 1;
    int o;
    for (i = x - 1; i > 1; i--)
    {
        if (x % i = 0)
        {
            o = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (o != 1)
    {
        o = 0;
    }

    return o;
}

int check_even(int x)
{
    int i;
    i = x / 2;

    if (i * 2 = x)
    {
        x = 1;
    }
    else x = 0;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int s = 0;

    while (s < 100)
    {
        while (1 = 1)
        {
            printf("Enter an odd number\n");
            scanf("%d , &a");
            b = check_odd(a);

            if (b = 1)
            {
                s = s + a;
                printf("Current sum equals %d , &s\n");
                break;
            }

            printf("Entered number is incorrect. Try again.\n");
        }

        while (1 = 1)
        {
            printf("Enter an even number\n");
            scanf("%d , &a");
            b = check_even(a);

            if (b = 1)
            {
                s = s + a;
                printf("Current sum equals %d , &s\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("Entered number is incorrect. Try again.\n");
        }
    }
printf("Sum equals $d , &s\n");
}
```

Now, I get lvalue errors with lines

```
if (x % i = 0)

if (i * 2 = x)
```

and

```
while (1 = 1)
```

What did I do wrong and why on earth would 1 = 1 statement give me an lvalue error? Also sorry for retarded code, just beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison operator in c is `==` not `=`, `=` is the assignment operator, so

```
while (1 = 1)
```

means assign `1` to `1` which is of course, impossible, change it to

```
while (1 == 1)
```

or even

```
while (1)
```

But a better condition for the while loop would be something like

```
while ((scanf("%d", &b) == 1) && (b % 2 != 0))
```

although you should be aware of the fact that the loop will end on invalid input, but you would prevent undefined behavior.

And, you have an error here

```
scanf("%d , &a");
```

you are passing the `&a` as part of the format string, which is wrong, it should be

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

please note that `scanf()` does not consume trailing white space characters, so you might need to manually extract them from the `stdin` buffer, by using `getchar()` or `fgetc()`.